# storm-starter's PrintSampleStream example instruction

Tags: java, apache-storm

the PrintSampleStream example in storm-starter project notes the following:

```
// to use this example, uncomment the twitter4j dependency information in the project.clj,
// uncomment storm.starter.spout.TwitterSampleSpout, and uncomment this class
```

the uncomment instructions are straightforward, but where is project.clj?

Answer (score 2):

File "project.clj" is in the root directory of the project. See the github https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter and uncomment twitter4j dependency in https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter/blob/master/project.clj.

Comment: i pulled from the new location, https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/tree/master/examples/storm-starter, which does not seem to have that file.  when i execute, mvn install, i get the error:  package twitter4j.conf does not exist

Comment: In new location if you check pom.xml they use 0.9.2-SNAPSHOT (not final version) and last release is apache-0.9.1 that not includes storm-starter yet, so I would use storm-starter from nathan github until they have a new release apache-0.9.2 stable. You will not have this problem.